# Why doesn't work (pushstate)

Tags: javascript, pushstate, history.js

I'm trying to use pushstate. But it doesn't work.
Actually, my "loadContent()" function doesn't work. It doesn't make any difference. I'll show u my codes.

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
        $('a').click(function(e) {
            $("#loading").show();
            href = $(this).attr("href");

            loadContent();

            // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
            history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
            e.preventDefault();


        });
        // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
            $("#loading").show();
            console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
            loadContent();
        };

    });

    function loadContent(){
        // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT

            $.ajax({
              url: "tema/project/content.php",
              success: function(e){

                    $(".main-div").empty();
                    $(".main-div").append(e);
              }
            });

    }
```

Content.php:

```
echo "this is my example to show me it does work.";
```

and there's some simple html codes that doesn't necessary.
OK i don't understand that, while the turn is on loadContent, there's nothing happen. It doesn't empty the 'main-div' it doesn't put any content it and there ne issue in chrome.

But why? why doesn't it work?

Any help?

Comment: Any error messages in the browser console? Try changing `dataType: "json"` to `dataType:"text"` - you're not loading JSON. What do you get with `alert(e)` just before the `.empty()` statement?

Comment: ok i've handled it, as u said i've changed json. there's no problem now. thx

Comment: use history.js plugin. you are putting it in the tags of your question but not in your code.